# C# HtmlTags library under asp core doesn't work for me

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to use the [C# HtmlTags](https://github.com/HtmlTags/htmltags) in my asp core project. I want to build a custom tag for my login.

Instead of writing this in my razor view all the time:

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
  </div>
```

I want to define this in my HelperClass:

```
    public static HtmlTag Login<T>(this IHtmlHelper<T> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<T, object>> expression,
        Action<HtmlTag> inputModifier = null)
    {
        inputModifier = inputModifier ?? (_ => { });
        var div = new HtmlTag("div");
        div.AddClass("form-control");
        var lbl = htmlHelper.LabelFor(expression);
        div.Append(lbl);
        return div;
    }
```

LabelFor(expression) returns the type IHtmlContent but the Append-methods needs the HtmlTag type. I can't convert it and that's why I am stuck.

I use HtmlTags.AspNetCore 4.2.0

Answer (score 1):

You are using the built in `HtmlHelper`, you should change to the `HtmlTags.Label` method:

```
public static HtmlTag Login<T>(this IHtmlHelper<T> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<T, object>> expression,
    Action<HtmlTag> inputModifier = null)
{
    inputModifier = inputModifier ?? (_ => { });
    var div = new HtmlTag("div");
    div.AddClass("form-control");
    var lbl = htmlHelper.Label(expression);
    div.Append(lbl);
    return div;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of Adding an HtmlTag, add a string with HTML:

```
public static string GetString(IHtmlContent content)
{
    var writer = new StringWriter();
    content.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
    return writer.ToString();
}
```

and add the result to the tag, like so:

```
tag.AppendHtml
```

Comment: If you're using this approach you don't need to create a new `StringWriter`, you you can get a `TextWriter` directly from the `ViewContext`. So this solution needlessly allocates new string objects in memory.

Comment: The ViewContext is not available in Asp Net Core, so yu can't get the TextWriter mentioned.

Comment: `StringWriter` **is** available in ASP.NET Core, because it's part of .NET Standard. It's located in `System.IO.StringWriter`.